# Add 2 vectors in JavaScript Vanilla

Tags: javascript

I'm reading "Eloquent JavaScript" and I've reached Chapter 6, 'The Secret Life of Objects' where I have to solve the exercises and I'm stuck at the 'add 2 vectors': https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html. In case you don't want to look at the condition in the book, here's it:

> Write a class `Vec` that represents a vector in two-dimensional space. It takes `x` and `y` parameters (numbers), which it should save to properties of the same name.

> Give the Vec prototype two methods, `plus` and `minus`, that take another vector as a parameter and return a new vector that has the sum or difference of the two vectors’ (this and the parameter) x and y values.

> Add a getter property `length` to the prototype that computes the length of the vector—that is, the distance of the point (x, y) from the origin (0, 0).

```
// Your code here.

console.log(new Vec(1, 2).plus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: 3, y: 5}
console.log(new Vec(1, 2).minus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: -1, y: -1}
console.log(new Vec(3, 4).length);
// → 5
```

How should I go about solving it?

This is what I did so far:

```js
class Vec {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  plus(x, y) {
    x += this.x;
    y += this.y;
    return `Vec {${x}, ${y}}`;
  }

  minus(x, y) {
    x -= this.x;
    y -= this.y;
    return `Vec{ x, y}`;
  }
}

Vec.prototype.toString = function() {
  return `${this.x} ${this.y}`;
};
```

Note that I didn't do the "getter length propriety" yet.

Here's what I got:

```
index.js:192 Vec {2 31, NaN}
```

I realise I haven't done almost anything properly. I'm asking cause I want to fix this.

Comment: *"I realise I haven't done almost anything properly.*" It's all in the instructions though: *"Give the Vec prototype two methods, plus and minus, that take another **vector** as a parameter and return a new **vector** [...]"* So: 1) your methods don't take a vector parameter but two numbers; and 2) don't return a new vector but a string.

Comment: You're returning a string. You need to call `new Vec()` to return a new vector.

Comment: You don't need to assign to `prototype` if you're using `class` syntax. Just add a `toString()` method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

`plus` and `minus` are supposed to take a `Vec` parameter, not separate `x` and `y` parameters. It should get the `x` and `y` values to add from the properties of the argument.

Then they should return a new vector, not a formatted string. If you want the output to look like the samples, you can convert the vectors to strings. I've modified your `toString()` method to make it format the vector as the examples show.

```js
class Vec {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  plus(otherVec) {
    return new Vec(this.x + otherVec.x, this.y + otherVec.y);
  }

  minus(otherVec) {
    return new Vec(this.x - otherVec.x, this.y - otherVec.y);
  }

  get length() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }

  toString() {
    return `Vec{x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}}`;
  }
}

console.log(String(new Vec(1, 2).plus(new Vec(2, 3))));
// → Vec{x: 3, y: 5}
console.log(String(new Vec(1, 2).minus(new Vec(2, 3))));
// → Vec{x: -1, y: -1}
console.log(new Vec(3, 4).length);
// → 5
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Now I understood how to actually do this.